# MutationObserver hangs in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11, mutation-observers

I am using MutationObserver to check when some nodes are removed and replaced by other new nodes to an element.

The following code works totally fine in Chrome, but on IE11 it just hangs.

If I change the addedNodes check with removedNodes, it works on IE11. I just don't understand why it hangs when I check for new nodes being added.

Any idea? I can't find any resources for this issue.

```js
var nodeToObserve = document.querySelector('#targetNode');

var callback = function(mutations, observer) {
  for (var index = 0; index < mutations.length; index) {
    var mutation = mutations[index];
    if (mutation.type === 'childList' && mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
      console.log(mutation);
      break;
    }

  }
  observer.disconnect();
}
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

observer.observe(nodeToObserve, {
  childList: true, // target node's children
  subtree: true // target node's descendants
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#targetNode {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
}

.childNode {
  //height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grandChildNode {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="targetNode">

</div>
```

Comment: on IE11 V11.228.17134.0 and win10 it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't incrementing the `index` in your `for` loop. Probably the results appear in a different order depending on the browser so the `if` statement will be triggered on some browsers but not others. Thus, the system will hang when the `if` statement isn't executed b/c of the infinite loop.

Comment: Omg, thank you! I can't believe I missed that!!! I think it is time for a break...

Comment: Haha happens to the best of us.